# Slideshow Timing Off

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can't seem to figure out why the timing of my slideshow is off, in section two of this page. It's almost acting erratic. I've checked the script and the timing seems to be correct. The slide show is in the second part of this page:

Scroll down.
Here's the page:
http://mudchallenger.com/fullpage/examples/a-test-5.html

I'm trying to get a 2 second fade and each image to hold for 5 seconds.

```
<div id="candy-wrapper">
<div id="candy-slideshow">
<div><img src="imgs/bg-fire.jpg" height="auto" width="100%"></div>
<div><img src="imgs/bg-runstart.jpg" height="auto" width="100%"></div>
<div><img src="imgs/bg-ice.png" height="auto" width="100%"></div>

<script>
   $("#candy-slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

setInterval(function() { 
  $('#candy-slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(2000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(2000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#candy-slideshow');
},  5000);
</script>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Change the timing like this

```
setInterval(function() { 
  $('#candy-slideshow > div:first')
    .fadeOut(2000)
    .next()
    .fadeIn(2000)
    .end()
    .appendTo('#candy-slideshow');
},  5000);
```

Second parameter in setInterval represent the time in milliseconds. If you change to 5000 means, the next method will execute only after 5 seconds.

Comment: Thank you, I should have clarified- I know how to change the interval timing, however it is not working correctly.  See my example with the updated intervals as specified in your code.

Comment: can you set up a fiddle for this?

Comment: I have tried but can't get the fiddle to work now. There's alot going on in the page: here's a link: --- http://jsfiddle.net/6Pw3z/--- Honestly, I'm not sure how to do that with so much going on in the page. (sorry!! I'm new with all of this).

Comment: So weird.   For some reason I checked it and swapped it out even, with the stuff you provided and it still is acting weird.  Do you see something conflicting?

If you look at the page, is my placement of the script off?
I have updated and reloaded the page...
http://mudchallenger.com/fullpage/examples/a-test-5.html

Comment: Awesome!   Thank you for your help.  Is there any way to crossfade rather than fade out and in?   Possibly another way to do the script?

I guess it was conflicting with something else in my page previously.

Comment: @user3769255 I didnt get  you. cross fade means?

Comment: @AnoopJoshi - Where the images fade over one another instead of fading to black in-between.  This is how it looks currently.... (it fades to black between images) http://mudchallenger.com/fullpage/examples/index-test.html  I cannot thank you enough for your kindness. I have had some real jerks respond to me before. Thank you.